# Sorting Imap mailbox by date using ImapMailbox.php

Tags: php, arrays, email

I have a customer support system which creates emails when an email is received. I used to postfix and a special configuration to get a hold of the emails to add extra features.

For example I want to include attachments that were sent from an email. The system doesnt do this , but creates an email with the subject , so I can include the attachments by matching the subjects.

I used ImapMailBox.php to read through the email contents.
It all works fine  but I am getting an issue fetching the last email, so I am gettign contents from any other email with the same subject , so I need to fetch the latest email.

```
 $mailboxP = new ImapMailbox('{127.0.0.1:143/novalidate-cert}',POSTFIX_EMAIL,POSTFIX_PASSWORD,ATTACHMENT_DIR, 'utf-8');
 foreach($mailbox->searchMails('ALL') as $mailId)
 $mail = $mailbox->getMail($mailId);
 $mailx=(array)$mail;
 $att=$mailx['attachments'];
```

I have tried using usort to the object $mail , with a function like this

```
      function 
     mysort($a,$b) {
    return strtotime($a->date)-strtotime($b->date);

     }
```

and to the array with a function like this

```
       function mysort($a,$b) {
       return strtotime($a['date'])-strtotime($b['date']);

         }
```

I have also tried using imap_sort to $mail and $mailx , but none of this works. 
errors I am getting

```
 imap_sort() expects parameter 1 to be resource, array given
 imap_sort() expects parameter 1 to be resource, object given
 usort() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given
 when passing an array I get undefined index date but it defined ..
```

Can anyone please be kind enough to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a function like this on ImapMailbox.php :

```
public function searchMailsSorted($imapCriteria = 'ALL') {
            $this->checkConnection();
            $mailsIds =imap_sort($this->mbox,SORTDATE,1,SE_UID,$imapCriteria,$this->serverEncoding);


            return $mailsIds ? $mailsIds : array();
    }
```

And then use it in your code like this:

```
 foreach($mailbox->searchMailsSorted('ALL') as $mailId)
{
 ///insert code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use Php rsort() function.

```
    <?php
$emailId = rsort($mailbox->searchMails('ALL');
?>
```